# gcc gdb no debugging info

Tags: debugging, gdb, g++, symbols

I'm trying to prevent g++ from inlining templated functions, which cause gdb to lack debugging information, like local variables or even current line numbers.

Actually, I'm guessing this is something related to inlining template functions, because this is the only situation where I can't have access to anything in my callstack.

I've pretty much tried everything I could in g++ options, such as:

```
-DDEBUG -O0 -fno-inline -fno-implicit-inline-templates
```

and even considered prefixing my functions with __attribute__ ((noinline)) to no effect.

My callstacks would look like

```
#0  CVector<CGatherColor>::operator[] (this=0x9324480, index=1208) at ../utils/vector.h:28
#1  0x0000000000ee1d27 in unsigned int CBrdfLoop::trace_t<CAreaLightSquare, CNoCulling, CAreaLightSquare, CBrdfLdSampler>(int, unsigned int, CPrimMBVH*, CVector<CBrdfCache::CVertexCache>*, CAreaLightSquare&, CNoCulling&, CAreaLightSquare&, CBrdfLoop::CVtxSmpInfo const&, CBrdfLdSampler&) ()
#2  0x0000000000eb52ac in void CBrdfLoop::illuminate_t<CAreaLightSquare, CAreaLightSquare, CBrdfLdSampler>(unsigned int, CBrdfLdSampler&, CVector<CBrdfCache::CVertexCache>*, CAreaLightSquare&, CAreaLightSquare&, unsigned int, CPrimMBVH*) ()
```

where there are no line numbers and no debugging information whatever I do. I'm compiling with g++ 4.4.5 and debugging with GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.1-34.fc13).

I'm quite stuck, and debugging is quite difficult, leaving me no options but printf... 
Is this a known issue of the versions I'm using, is there anything I can do?

Update: With more recent versions of gcc/gdb, no problem. Seems like a gcc/gdb bug.

Comment: Captain Obvious: do you use -g? It is not listed in the options you tried

Comment: Yup, I'm using -ggdb which apparently makes sure I have debugging info for gdb... Here are my compile options:

`g++ -c -DDEBUG -O0 -fno-inline -fno-implicit-inline-templates   -Wno-deprecated -ggdb -Wall -fPIC -MD -msse2`

Comment: *note* `-fno-implicit-inline-templates` according to the documentation "don't emit code", so it actually makes the issue worse.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use -g3 symbol to get the detailed debugging information. That will produce complete code level information which can be used in debugging the flow.