# How to setup C++ with debugger on mac in visual studio code

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I am trying to setup visual studio code to build/run and debug c++ files using g++ compiler on macOS. However when I build or debug the code, I can see that output file is created and i can run it as well however i am not able to debug it in vscode, for debugging gives weird behaviour.

So far I have been able to write tasks which builds the .cpp file and and executes it. The output comes into the terminal of vscode. However when I try with debug a new Terminal opens and no breakpoint is hit.

Here is the tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build with g++",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
        "-Wall",
        "-Wextra",
        "-Wpedantic",
        "-std=c++11",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "run",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cd ${fileDirname}/ && ./${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "dependsOn": ["Build with g++"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is my launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(lldb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "showDisplayString": false,
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "logging": {
        "moduleLoad": false,
        "programOutput": true,
        "trace": false
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "Build with g++",
      "osx": {
        "MIMode": "lldb"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect that when i hit debug or press f5 the terminal in the vscode should run and I am able to debug the program.

Comment: +1 Because I'm curious as to the answer to this question as well.  My google-fu has failed me, although the answer will probably be a link to an instructional "how to set-up VSC on/for Mac" web page.

Comment: add `-g` to your build command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc gdb no debugging info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137027/gcc-gdb-no-debugging-info)

Answer (score 0):

#### It IS indeed possible to RUN and DEBUG C++ in VSCode on MacOS with I/O in the Integrated Console.

---

Extensions:

- CodeLLDB
- (Optional) C/C++ Extension Pack by Microsoft

Once you have CodeLLDB installed, open the Command Palette (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), and run:

```
> Open extensions folder
```

Navigate to the folder named `vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.xx.xx` (where `x` is just a version number), then open the subfolder `lldb/bin/`.

**THEN, delete the file called `debugserver`.**

Assuming that your C++ code was compiled with the `-g` flag (for debug symbols), you can debug your program using the following configuration in your `.vscode/launch.json` configuration:

```json
    {
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Build and Debug C++ (OSX/LLDB)",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/main",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      // "preLaunchTask": "C++: build program with g++",
      // You can adjust the above line if you already have a task
      // in your tasks.json configured to compile your program
      // (Make sure it gets compiled with -g so it can be debugged!)
    },
```

Set your breakpoints appropriately, and start debugging with this new configuration. Your program's console I/O will be handled by the integrated terminal, and any debugging (logpoints or evaluating expressions with lldb) happens in the Debug Console.

---

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

As @alan-birtles pointed out adding -g would be the solution. 
Also I found out [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/390#issuecomment-488802272) that there is no way to use integrated terminal of vscode for c++ as lldb doesn't support it.

Here are the final configuration.

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(lldb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "showDisplayString": false,
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "logging": {
        "moduleLoad": false,
        "programOutput": true,
        "trace": false
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "Build with g++",
      "osx": {
        "MIMode": "lldb"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

task.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build with g++",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "-Wall",
        "-Wextra",
        "-Wpedantic",
        "-std=c++11",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "run",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cd ${fileDirname}/ && ./${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "dependsOn": ["Build with g++"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your `VSCode Debugger Extension` has bugger.

Successfully Setup C++ Debug with VSCode on mac:
I use `clang/gcc` as compiler, `Code-Runner`(VSCode Extension) as runner, `C/C++ Clang Command Adopter`(VSCode Extension) as to provide static detection, `CodeLLDB`(VSCode Extension) to debug C++.
Do Not Download `Microsoft C/C++` (Identifier: `ms-vscode.cpptools`, for C/C++
IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing. Microsoft Officially produced Extension), Because This CPPtools and that CodeLLDb conflict.

To avoid any issues, please do not download any VSCode Extensions yet.
Here is my configuration about debug C++ with VSCode on mac:
`VSCode v1.63.2`;

`Code Runner v0.11.6` (Author: Jun Han）

`C/C++ Clang Command Adapter v0.2.4` (Author: Yasuaki MITANI）

`CodeLLDB v1.4.5` (Author: Vadim Chugunov)

`Clang v9.0.0` `gcc v4.2.1` `Intel CPU` `macOS 10.12`

Details of successful configuration refer to here：

[Debug C++11 manually with VSCode(mac)](https://gist.github.com/SofijaErkin/92144b34cb7b584875b61714ff425cd8)